# .NET profiler shows contentions on string handling

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking, stringbuilder

I've been profiling my app for thread contentions because of performance issues, and found a lot of contentions in a class that concats a lot of strings. My code looks like this:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder(); //some contentions here (WHY?)

var copy = string.Copy(existingString); //some here (understandable)

builder.Append(Escape(copy)); //a LOT of contentions here (most of them on Append(), some on Escape())
```

Escape(string) looks like this (all the private vars are private readonly static strings, defined inline)

```
private static string Escape(string str)
{
    return str
        .Replace(_backSlash, _escapedBackSlash) //double backslash
        .Replace(_quote, _escapedQuote) //quote

        .Replace(_newline, string.Empty) //line break
        .Replace(_return, string.Empty) //carriage return
        .Replace(_tab, string.Empty) //tab
        .Replace(_verticalTab, string.Empty) //vertical tab (i know, right?)

        .Replace(_dataLink, string.Empty); //data link char escape
    }
}
```

My question is, why do I get contentions on rows where I only create a new instance of `StringBuilder`, calling `Append` on that `StringBuilder` or calling `stringInstance.Replace` on a string that is explicitly copied. All these should be local variables so there should be no lock contentions, right? What am I missing?

Comment: Contention for the GC heap lock is very likely here.  It is pretty important to provide a decent estimate the Capacity of the StringBuilder or you'll die a death by a thousand needle pricks.  You ought to see a high rate of soft page faults as a side-effect. Further improve the outcome by moving to .NET 4 and using server GC.

Comment: I used 3.5. I now switched to 4.0, which did not make much of a difference. I've also specified the capacity of the stringbuilder and it helped. Will try using server GC.

Comment: Using server GC and avoiding creating new stringbuilders (reusing the same one instead) seems to help with the issue. Now the most contentions are on rows cloning a dictionary: var d = new Dictionary<K,V>(oldDic); Is this a related issue? The GC heap lock?

Comment: @HansPassant I think the GC issue was the problem here. Will you write it as an answer so I can accept it?